# I am not able to control my Keyboard back light(Asus TUF Gaming Aus Aura RGB)

Tags: 20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and I am unable to control the lighting control of the keyboard and I have tried rogauracore-retool this from GitHub but every time I use it returns Could not find ROG Aura Core keyboard, so any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for an alternative for aura sync and finally I have come up with a tool. https://github.com/legacyO7/TUF-Aurora
Maybe this might help you

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks! https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore didn't.